# How to add UISlider into a bottom Toolbar?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, toolbar, uislider

Is there any way to add a UISlider into a Toolbar, I need to add some other objects also. I am creating a tabbar based application with tableview. And I don't want to hide the tabbar.
   [image]
please check the figure.

Comment: Just add it as a `subView` to your toolBar. Simple !

Comment: thank you for your reply. i used the following code for adding toolbar [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];
[self.navigationController.toolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent]; How can I modify this one with slider? please show some sample code if you can.
[self.navigationController.toolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 322, 320, 110)];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create your `customUIView` or `customUIToolBar` with frame size (0, 322, 320, 110)
2. Add two `UIButtons` (with right frame size) in it with `addSubView` property.

   [self.customToolBar addSubView:button];
3. Add that green thing image as you have shown in your question as a `subView`.
4. Add a UISlider as a subview.
5. `[self.view addSubView: customUIToolBar];`